# Is "alone at night" an adjective or an adverb in this sentence?

Tags: modifiers

In [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8EY8zGm6ECU&feature=emb_logo) about the *Diagramming of Gerunds and Gerund Phrases* that guy is diagramming this sentence:

> *"Walking alone at night is scary."*

He first categorised **'walking'** as a noun since it is a verbal. However, he then proceeds to categorise **'alone at night'** as an adverb modifying **'walking'**. Shouldn't alone at night be an adjective since walking is a noun?

Comment: 'Walking alone at night' is a noun phrase. It's like 'Darkness is scary'/ Walking alone at night is scary.  'Alone at night' qualifies the verbal noun 'walking'.

Answer (score 2):

The word "walking" is a gerund working as a noun, the subject of "is". The word "alone" is an adverb, and "at night" is a preposition phrase working as an adverb.

See:
[dailywritingtips "gerunds"](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/gerunds/)

> Like a verb, a gerund can take objects and be modified by adverbs and adverbial phrases, but its function in a sentence is to serve as a noun–a noun that ends in -ing.

Comment: I think I sort of understand what you mean. Please correct me if I interpreted your answer wrongly. 
Although 'walking' functions as a noun, it is not strictly a noun. Though it describes the concept of walking-which is a noun-'alone' modifies the action of walking. Together, 'walking' and 'alone' forms a noun phrase. In this sense, 'alone' doesn't function as an adjective because 'walking' is still ultimately a verb describing an action, thus requiring an adverb.

Comment: Yes, you have it right.

Comment: @LeeZhiyuan  Walking is a noun in that sentence.  But the word walking could be an adjective or a present participle in another sentence.  The last sentence in your comment is correct.